# ios 8 uitableView delegate method gets called before viewDidAppear on unwind segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

It appears that in ios8 the way the tableview triggers the delegate method has changed, for example if you take a  look at my example and run the project is xcode 5 and then in xcode 6 youll notice that in xcode 6 the items are added to the table without me explicitly inserting the object into the table. 
Is this is a change with the ios8? and if so I cant seem to find anything online that said that the was changing?...
The code in question is simply this method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{



    NSLog(@" this is the count %lu", (unsigned long)[tableItems.LocationsObjectArray count] );

    return [tableItems.LocationsObjectArray count];

}
```

Anyways to replicate what I'm trying to prove. Take at  look at the public project. fire it up on xcode 5 and run it. Click on one of the cells in the table. Then click `Add Item` Once you click on add item click the button labeled `button` youll noticed that in xcode 6 it will perform the unwind segue and automatically add the value to the table. Where as in Xcode 5 you have to create an insert object method to actually insert the value into the table. I think the reason is because in xcode 6 the `numberOfRowsInSection` runs even before the `viewdidAppear` gets called.

sample [project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eg7pfzrtrccylmu/AAB9hk1WmligqGS9ClgQeFWPa?dl=0) here

Comment: You linked to a single file, not the project.

Comment: Do not post a link to your project and expect people to do a full code review. Update your question with just the relevant code in the question.

Comment: It does appear that numberOfRowsInSection is called sometime between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear when you come back to the table view. This doesn't happen in iOS 7. I haven't been able to find any documentation for this yet either. In iOS 7, you would have to manually call reloadData for this to happen (but reloadData is not being called in iOS 8 when you just come back to a table view).

Comment: @maddy I was not trying to get a full code review i was simply trying to point out a difference between ios8 and ios7 that causes me several nights of debugging. I wanted to see if i was doing something wrong or is this in fact something different between both versions. At the very least it appears that this not working as expected and i wanted to save others the time i had already spent. If you feel that this question is not viable i would delete.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks for verifying i thought I was making a mistake.

Comment: hey folks any update on this?